# Cannot create flutter project or run flutter project in Android studio. (flutter works fine)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm getting into flutter so I followed the install doc on the website and had no issue, installed the flutter and dart plug-ins on both Android Studio and Intelli J. The `flutter doctor -v` command results in the following [image]

But yet when I try to create a new flutter project in Android Studio a folder is created with the project name but it is empty and I get the following in the event button on the welcome screen.

> Error creating project
>
> Flutter create command was unsuccessful

So I decided to create the project manually in gitbash where the create command worked perfectly.

I opened the project in Android Studio and discovered another problem even with the emulator running or phone attached the devices section of the run ribbon displays no device and always says loading in the dropdown when clicked.

So again I opened gitbash and in the project root folder type `flutter run` and the default flutter test app appeared on the emulator.

In Summary, Android studio can open but not create the project nor can it run it but the project can be run from gitbash on the emulator I launched from Android studio.

BTW: IntelliJ has a similar result when creating a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what was causing the issue but a fresh install of Git seems to have resolved the issues.

Comment: how to do so @javaScrub ?